# Error in pom.xml when create new maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

when I create new maven project, an error in the default pom.xml that: Exception java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties [in thread "Worker-11: Creating project "DemoShop""]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.g2.demoshop</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoShop</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail. What version of Eclipse? What version of Java?

Comment: I use: "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2022-03";
'java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22';
"Apache Maven 3.8.5"

Comment: It looks like something is trying to use reflection on the Properties class - which modern versions of Java don't allow. We need to see the log to know what is doing that.